# Saving code online (Java Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, version-control, eclipse-plugin

Currently I'm saving an online copy of my code on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). I was wondering if there is any other convenient option, such as an Eclipse plugin (that can maybe do this automatically?).

*Note: The project's code is private and I'm thus looking for an option that doesn't make it public.*

Comment: GitHub = source control. If your looking to get a job you'll want Git on your CV

Comment: to supplement Blundell's answer, there are Git and Github plugins for Eclipse

Comment: I can really recommend using Github.

Comment: bitbucket is also an alternative to github

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you considered putting your code in an online repository? BitBucket gives you free unlimited Git or Mercurial repositories and they both work with Eclipse. You can also use SVN, and eclipse has a plugin for it with the name of Subclipse. and it works perfect.

Comment: +1 For bitbucket, free even if you don't want open source your code. There is a team limit though per repo, but for 1 person, it's pretty much perfect.

Comment: Another +1 for the bitbucket tip. I've been after exactly this for a long time, and I've no idea how it slipped me by. Private repo with public issue tracker has, until now, not been something I've found anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are several free source management systems out there.
However - if you want to use them freely you'll need to opensource your code.
Check out [github](https://github.com/) or [googlecode](http://code.google.com/) for example.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a SCM tool (Source Control Management). GIT or Subversion are the things you are looking for. Have a look at [Github.com](http://github.com) or [Google Code](http://code.google.com) (ups sorry I didn't notice that you're looking for a *private* solution). BitBouquet is probably the best public server for closed source. If you have your own server (i.e. on a cloud), or you may install [GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/) or [Gitosis](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) tools; for subversion you can set up your own server following my [tutorial](http://en.newinstance.it/2009/08/27/tutorial-ubuntu-904-apache-with-ssl-subversion-over-http-https-and-trac/).

Eclipse supports CVS and Subversion built-in, afaik. Maybe latest versions also have git; by the way there is Egit eclipse plugin to support Git.